# Why won't Field Pack List 2.1.1 work?

Tags: ee2, error, fieldtype, field-pack, list

I am using Field Pack 2.1.1 with EE 2.9.0.

All field types are working except the List field type.  Are these compatible? Is there an alternative field type I could substitute with ease?

I have maybe 200 entires using this field type with 5-10 list items each so I am assume it would be painful to migrate away.  Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I've just upated from EE2.8.1 to EE 2.9.0 the List field type from Field Pack 2.1.1, is working fine.

Comment: "not working" ... in what way? Describe the behaviour you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the lack of clarity,  I have figured this out and will detail it in case someone makes the same mistake I made.  I have been working with EE to long to make this type of mistake, but figured detailing may help others.

**What this looked like on my end:**  The field type appear to install correctly, but when attempting to edit a page using this field type, I could not add or edit any of my list items.

**What I did wrong:** I accidentally uploaded the field type code to both `system/expressionengine/third_party` and `themes/third_party`.  Obviously the module's theme code needs to go in the themes folder, but in a rush to update I accidentally made this incorrect upload.

**How I found the problem:** I went to an edit page containing the List field type and did an inspect element.  Then noticed 404 errors saying that the field type's css and js couldn't be found.  Since these were supposed to be located in the `themes/third_party` folder, checking this folder I found the incorrect folder had been uploaded.

**Solution:** (Which is very obvious at this point) Upload the modules theme folder to the server's `themes/third_party` folder

Comment: Sometimes I made a simple, and stupid error, and I can loose a lot of time, because I believe it's something more complex.